# Replace div after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $("#p").replaceWith($("#p1"));
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="p">This is a paragraph.</div>
<div id="p1">Replacement</div>
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works fine until I put form action.. When I keep that submit in a form, this code does not work. How can i replace that div after form submit. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you want form to be submitted ?

Comment: yes i want to replace this `<div id="p">This is a paragraph.</div>` with this `<div id="p1">Replacement</div>` after form submission.

Comment: Once form is submitted, page is unloaded hence all the script which is executed is unset...

Comment: You are right, exactly that's happening

Comment: Either stop form submission or use `ajax` to submit the form..

Comment: Let me try with ajax form submission

Comment: @Pooojaaaa can you update you code with your form tags?

Comment: I tried with ajax did not work

Comment: @HenryDev updated.. After form submission the page get refreshed and the script getting unset

Comment: @Pooojaaaa I just posted my solution. Did it help you?

Comment: I have a question why is this question has PHP tag, This is a simple application of jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(event){
    $("#p").replaceWith($("#p1").text());
    return false;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p">This is a paragraph.</div>
<div id="p1">Replacement</div>
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes it worked , let me try this with my original code.. thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

you need `text` method for that . 
you were removing entire element before . you need to remove only text value

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $("#p").replaceWith($("#p1").text());
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="p">This is a paragraph.</div>
<div id="p1">Replacement</div>

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But this also does the same, after form submission the script is getting unset & returning me the first paragraph only

Comment: @Pooojaaaa it is 2 paragraph with 1 button . see carefully

Comment: I m doing that only

Answer (score 0):

Specify what to replace it with:

```
 $(this).replaceWith("<div><p>Replacement</p></div>");
```

Comment: This is just a example , i want to load a whole more data

Comment: Include it in the argument. Thing is this can be achieved many ways but best would be to use AJAX, how to achieve it with AJAX is another question beyond the scope of your current.

Answer (score 0):

Form submission needs to be done using AJAX then only you can achieve this which you want to do.

Otherwise the form will submit and page will refresh which will result to re initialization of script.

Answer (score 0):

As Pooojaaqaa and Rayon mention the when the action attribute is set on the form tag, the form is submitted and the page is reloaded (even if `action="#"`).  To catch this action you need to catch the form's `submit` event, not the button's `click` event.  In the `submit` event handler you need to call `preventDefault()` on the event object passed into the handling function like below.

```html
<form id="frmSearch" action="#" method="get">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

```js
$("#frmSearch").submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $("#p").replaceWith($("#p1").text());
});
```